# FOSElasticaBundle - Symfony

Tags: symfony

**When I try to access my search page, I got this error.**

It works on my local machine but not on the server I got the error below.

Any idea of what might be causing this error?

> [2017-09-14 11:49:57] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   RuntimeException: "Cannot find corresponding Doctrine objects (0) for
>   all Elastica results (21). IDs: 35, 42, 47, 54, 59, 61, 66, 73, 112,
>   117, 124, 129, 24, 31, 36, 43, 50, 62, 67, 106, 113" at
>   /srv/www/ribambel.com/httpdocs/server/vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/Doctrine/AbstractElasticaToModelTransformer.php
>   line 90 {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Cannot find
>   corresponding Doctrine objects (0) for all Elastica results (21). IDs:
>   35, 42, 47, 54, 59, 61, 66, 73, 112, 117, 124, 129, 24, 31, 36, 43,
>   50, 62, 67, 106, 113 at
>   /srv/www/ribambel.com/httpdocs/server/vendor/friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle/Doctrine/AbstractElasticaToModelTransformer.php:90)"}
>   []

1. I've searched on the internet and most of the answers that I got was
   to run the populate command but it did not work.
2. And some research lead me to this one.

   elastica_to_model_transformer:

   ignore_missing: true

**When I run the php "app/console fos:elastica:populate":**

On my Local Machine:

> Resetting search    0/336 [>---------------------------]   0%
>
> %message%
>
> 100/336 [========>-------------------]  29%
>
> Populating search/webediacontent
>
> 200/336 [================>-----------]  59%
>
> Populating search/webediacontent
>
> 300/336 [=========================>--]  89%
>
> Populating search/webediacontent
>
> 336/336 [============================] 100%
>
> Populating search/webediacontentRefreshing search
>
> Refreshing search

On server:

> Resetting search
>
> 124/124 [============================] 100%
>
> Populating search/webediacontentRefreshing search
>
> Refreshing search

Comment: Actually this error appears when you have indexes that does not match with database values. That's why the solution is to populate.. Do you have any error when you try to populate ?

Comment: No error. I have updated my post to show the different outputs when running the command on my local and  server.